# Javascript contact list

Tags: javascript

Hi i have coded a simple contact list application in JavaScript. I have created a search function which shows all the list of contacts when ran. I am just wondering how i would when the function is run to output the returns like this:

1. First Name:
2. Last Name:
3. Number:
4. Address:

As at the moment it shows my output names at the top but then shows my 'friend' variable code below that.

My JavaScript Code is below:

```
var friends = {

bill: {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Stevens",
    number: "07872937209",
    address: ['Park Road', 'Blaby','Leicester', 46]

    },
steve:{
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Elliott",
    number: "07970943757",
    address: ['Park Road2', 'Blaby2','Leicester2', 462]
    }
};

var list = function(object)
{
    for(var key in object){
        console.log(key);
        }
    };

    var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friendsName;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling your `list` and `search` functions, with what arguments? What's wrong with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've created a new function called `print` that will output the specific person in the format you want.

```
function print(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (k === 'address') {
      console.log(obj[k].join(', '));
    } else {
      console.log(obj[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

One thing that you needed to look out for in this function is that `firstName` will never `===` `name`. `firstName` starts with a capital letter and the name (or object key) is in lowercase so the `===` will never return true. Here I've used `toLowercase()` to correct this.

```
function search(name) {
  for (var prop in friends) {
    if (friends[prop].firstName.toLowerCase() === name) {
      print(friends[prop]);
    }
  }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp68n/2)

One thing I noticed is that you'll not be able to have more than one person with the same nickname (the keys in your object) because all object keys are unique. You might find the following useful.

In short I took the liberty of switching your friends object to an array (adding a new nickname key) and included a `fetchFriend` function that uses [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to pull those objects from the array that match the nickname you pass in. Then you can loop over the returned array regardless how many people you've nicknamed "bill" in your friends list:

```
var friends = [
  {
    nickname: 'bill',
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Stevens",
    number: "07872937209",
    address: ['Park Road', 'Blaby', 'Leicester', 46]
  },
  {
    nickname: 'bill',
    firstName: "William",
    lastName: "Fisher",
    number: "078729234209",
    address: ['Moose Road', 'Whitby', 'Yorkshire', 146]
  },
  {
    nickname: 'steve',
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Elliott",
    number: "07970943757",
    address: ['Park Road2', 'Blaby2', 'Leicester2', 462]
  }
];

function list(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].firstName);
  }
};

function print(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (k === 'address') {
      console.log(obj[k].join(', '));
    } else {
      console.log(k + ': ' + obj[k]);
    }
  }
}

function fetchFriend(nickname, arr) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.nickname === nickname;
  });
}

function search(nickname, friends) {
  var friendArr = fetchFriend(nickname, friends);
  for (var i = 0, l = friendArr.length; i < l; i++) {
    print(friendArr[i]);
  }
};

search('bill', friends);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp68n/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! that sorted everything out and i learnt some great things :)

Comment: NP. I should point out that `filter` only works on IE v9 and above, but there's a polyfill [at the bottom of this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you need to use an older version in your work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Stevens",
        number: "07872937209",
        address: ['Park Road', 'Blaby', 'Leicester', 46]
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Elliott",
        number: "07970943757",
        address: ['Park Road2', 'Blaby2', 'Leicester2', 462]
    }
};

var list = function (object)
{
    for (var key in object) 
    {
        console.log(key);
    }
};

var search = function (name)
 {
    for (var prop in friends)
        {
        if (friends[prop].firstName === name) 
           {
               var index = 1;
               for (var entity in friends[prop]) {
                //add if logic for formating the op
                console.log(index + ". " + entity + " " + friends[prop][entity]);
                index++;
            }

            return;
        }
    }
};
```